# upload and display image in circular image json android

Tags: php, android, image, upload, display

```
<?php

$dir = 'uploads/';

if (isset($_REQUEST['image'])) {
    $base = $_REQUEST['image'];
    $current_timestamp = time();
    $current_timestamp = (string)$current_timestamp;
    $filename = $current_timestamp . '-' . basename($_REQUEST['filename']);

    $binary = base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen($dir . $filename, 'wb');

    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);

    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    echo $filename;
}
```

Image upload Not working

Upload and Display image in Circular Image view Android JSON PHP

Comment: You should start with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of SO, because I'm not sure what your are really asking for

Comment: how exactly is it not working? What is the actual result, and what do you expect? And how do you upload?

Comment: @VladMatvienko image gets uploaded but i want to view in circular image view in android is there any coding

Comment: So you basically want to circle the ImageView, right? Have you tried searching?

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes i tried searching but i didn't find any solution.. can you help me...

Comment: the search query is `android circle imageview`

Answer (score 0):

So I modified your code. Try this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['image'])){ 

    $base = $_REQUEST['image'];
    $current_timestamp = time();
    $current_timestamp = (string)$current_timestamp; 
  $filename = $current_timestamp . '-' . basename($_REQUEST['filename']);
    $base = str_replace(' ','+', $base); 
    $binary = base64_decode($base);  
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; 
charset=utf-8'); 
    $file = fopen($dir . $filename, 'wb'); 
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file); header('Content-Type: text/html'); 
    echo $filename;
```

}